# Error in email validation regular expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, email-validation

I am trying to validate my email address field at client side using jQuery and regular expression but some reason javaScript complaining by syntax error in regular expression as

```
@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})
```

out of

```
/^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i;
```

### jQuery Function

```
$('.emailField').change(function () {

    var inputVal = $(this).val();

    var emailReg = /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i;

    if (!emailReg.test(inputVal)) {

        $(this).after('<span class="error error-keyup-7">Invalid Email Format.</span>');
    }

});
```

[image]

Comment: Weird, it's working fine on my end.

Comment: Where did you get that regex? It probably doesn't work for most of the domains on this list: http://www.newtldlist.com/

Comment: @ toxic you code in working fine on my end too. I found one thing you need to remove the `<span class="error error-keyup-7">Invalid Email Format.</span>` before , otherwise it will append next to previous.[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rztvzr7c/)

Comment: do I need to add some library to add expression in javaScript???

Comment: I have partial view in ASP.NET-MVC in which I added code block in <script type="text/javascript">

Comment: @toxic Script tag is fine. `<script>` works too. No extra library required.

Comment: i have upload error screen shot in my question above

Comment: That's probably just the linter failing to recognize the regex. Have you tried running it on a browser if it throws an error?

Comment: What happens when you run it on the browser? Does console display any error message?

Comment: Try this regex: `/[^@]+@[^@]+/` ;-)

Comment: I have create separate plugin for that and call in my partial view and it worked! code updated in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have create separate plugin for that and call in my partial view and it worked!

```
(function ($) {

   $.fn.validateEmail = function (_email) {

      alert(_email);

      var re = /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i;

      return re.test(_email);
   };

}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 1):

try with below code using JavaScript RegExp constructor Property. read more
[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

```
var emailReg = new RegExp(/^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i);
if (!emailReg.test(inputVal)) {
      $(this).after('<span class="error error-keyup-7">Invalid Email Format.</span>');
}
```

Comment: no again syntax error in expression from @((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})

Comment: i have code block in <script type="text/javascript"> ... am I doing right?

Comment: No no need to add extra liberary

Comment: that is very strange!

Comment: i have upload error screen shot in my question above

Comment: Have you check code in browser?? Is there any error in browser console??

Comment: I have create separate plugin for that and call in my partial view and it worked! code updated in my answer

Comment: thats great . +1 for your answer . :)

Comment: Happy to help you . you can accept your own answer and close this question :)